# Best function/method to access wp-config?

Tags: wp-config

I have a developer who is accessing the wp-config file directly to get database information. I would think that WP has a better way to do this. What do you think community?

Comment: Global $wpdb; http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: I suppose it depends specifically what database information you're talking about, not sure `$wpdb` holds data on the database name, the user or password(for the db connection), so including may be the only sure way to grab that info in a reliable manner unless you're happy to hardcode that info and update it from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a Wordpress function to do this. But have a look at this search and replace tool:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

This achieves what you want by reading in the wp-config file and scanning through it. Have a look at the function "icit_srdb_define_find" on line 374.